# Property or method ... is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I am writing a sample Vue component that works with an Event.

I get this error by rendering the index.html: "Property or method "onCouponApplied" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render" in the console.

index.html

```
<div id="root">
    <coupon @applied="onCouponApplied"></coupon>
</div>
```

and below is Vue codes

main.js

```
window.Event = new Vue();

Vue.component('coupon',{
    template: `<input placeholder="Enter" @blur="onCouponApplied">`,
    methods:{
        onCouponApplied() {Event.$emit('applied');}
    }
})

new Vue({
    el:"#root",
    created() {
        Event.$on('applied', ()=>alert('Received'));
    },
});
```

Comment: You are calling `onCouponApplied` on the root component, not `coupon` component, meanwhile you are declaring `onCouponApplied` method on coupon component, that's why `onCouponApplied` is not defined

Comment: Why are using `Event.$emit('applied');` instead of `this.$emit('applied');` ?

Comment: @palaѕн because I want to replace Event with a class later. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Vue template code doesn't belong in index.html: `<div id="root"></div>`

Then you're mixing up event-bus and normal custom Vue events.
It's either:

```
window.Event = new Vue();

Vue.component("coupon", {
  template: `<input placeholder="Enter" @blur="onCouponApplied">`,
  methods: {
    onCouponApplied() {
      Event.$emit("applied");
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `<coupon></coupon>`,
  created() {
    Event.$on("applied", () => alert("Received"));
  },
});
```

or:

```
Vue.component("coupon", {
  template: `<input placeholder="Enter" @blur="$emit('applied')">`,
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `<coupon @applied="onCouponApplied"></coupon>`,
  methods: {
    onCouponApplied() {
      alert("Received");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why did you use `#app` for element in new instance of Vue?

Comment: I think he just used it to show the sample code. You can still use `#root` and it will still work fine like this.

Comment: Why it doesn't work without defining template `<coupon>` in new instance of Vue?

Comment: Yea sorry, replace #app by #root.


You only put valid and static html in index.html.

`<coupon>` is a Vue component and need to be used within a Vue component or instance which import Coupon component locally or globally. Furthermore `@applied="onCouponApplied"` has no meaning in pure HTML.

Comment: @Renaud I examined it with `v-on:applied="onCouponApplied"` and omitted that `template` in the Vue instance. The error was remained in the console, but it functioned correctly. It's peculiar.